# Jupyter Kernel conda set to 3.10 but terminal switches to 3.11?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

Working in VSCode (1.86.2) on an iMac (14.3.1): I created a conda environment and selected python 3.10 as the interpreter (one of the libraries I am working with doesn't work with anything above 3.10), then start a new terminal and I can see that the environment is activated.

I then start installing things and it switches to 3.11? What is that about? I checked with `python --version` and I get `Python 3.10.13`. I checked the .conda/bin and the libraries are there.

Terminal says this `(/path/to/directory/Project/.conda) (.conda) (base) My-iMac:Project D$`

[image: screenshot]

Comment: @JialeDu I'm afraid not. I was doing what you suggested already when the problem occurred and it is still occurring.

Comment: What's still happening? Can you tell me what you did? And then what did you get? But what did you want? What's the difference between what you got?

Answer (score 0):

please try to follow these steps:

```
    $ conda create -n myenv python=3.10
    $ conda activate myenv
    $ python --version
    $ conda install --no-update-deps <package-name-here> # if you need to install any package in this env
    $ which python
```

The output should point to the Python interpreter in your conda environment.

So, just use this env created in your VSCode.

PS - If it doesn't, you might need to adjust your PATH variable.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the kernel you choose for jupyter has nothing to do with the terminal, it doesn't affect the terminal's python environment.

If you choose an interpreter (virtual environment) for `.py` scripts,

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> --> `Python: Select Interpreter`

[image]

then a new terminal will automatically activate the environment.

[image]